# Comparing multiple values in an if statement - Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Can you compare multiple values in a single if statement in Ruby? If so, how? I know in other languages, you would just use a double ampersand (&&), but I have never seen any example or documentation about it, even in the official ruby documentation! Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Did you try *anything* before asking?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sergio, you are one of my favorite responders here on SO and I am grateful for your wisdom but I wonder... are the questions starting to get to you?

Comment: @ScottJShea: yes, sometimes. Not this one, though :)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare multiple values"? Checking if `a` is either `1` or `2`?

Comment: Im sorry, geez. I DID try things, but apparently I screwed it up somehow and I came to the conclusion that my methods were not adequate, and that there must not be a way to compare multiple values. I came here to double-check.

Comment: @SuperSN While I was not one who voted you down I did kind of pile on. I should have posted something constructive. Showing some code (even if it is broken) helps a lot and it helps others when they search for help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `&&` operator

```
if a == 1 && b == 2
  # do things
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It IS in the documentation.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UG

Comment: The first edition of the Pickaxe shouldn't be considered reliable "documentation" these days.

Comment: Yes you are right, in a very strict sense, one would have to refer to the specification of the Ruby language. But I guess the Pickaxe is still the one most people would read.

Comment: @Innerpeacer I'm curious what "specification" you refer to.

Comment: @Innerpeacer Nothing against the pickaxe. But I think the *first edition*, which the online version is, was for Ruby 1.6!

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Sadly, only the first edition is available online. The final draft specification of Ruby (linked from wikipedia) is at: http://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/ruby_draft_specification_agreement.html